# How can I make an image to be not trasparent and text to not scroll beside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the first time I'm writing in HTML language, forgive me if I don't respect the language formatting standards.

```js
function show_or_hide_Block(show_hide){
    if (document.getElementById(show_hide).className == 'hide') {
        document.getElementById(show_hide).className = "show";} 
 else{document.getElementById(show_hide).className = "hide";}
}

 function banner_adapt () {
  var b = document.getElementById("banner");
  b.style.maxWidth="100%";
  var p = document.getElementById("body_text");
   if (b.width >= 700){
    //alert("actual: " + b.width + " too large, setting to 700px.")
    b.style.maxWidth="700px";
   } else if (b.width < 700){
    //alert("Enought small to set 100%.")
    b.style.maxWidth="100%";}
   //alert("setting lar to:" + (Math.round(b.width/1600*449)+10) + "px");
   p.style.marginTop=(Math.round(b.width/1600*449)+10)+ "px";
   
 }

  $(window).load(function(){
   banner_adapt();
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
   banner_adapt();
  });
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f6db75;
}

separatore_iniziale {
  margin-top: 60px;
  }

top_menu {
  font-size: 18px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 10px;
  }

bottom_menu {
  font-size: 18px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 25px;
  }

.ver {
  font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

.altro {
  font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
p{
 z-index: 2;
}

h1{
  margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

h2{
  font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

h3{
  font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

h3.hide {
  display: none;
}

h3.show {
  
}

h4{
  margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
  }

.tab {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  }


ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<top_menu>
<h1><a  href="./index.html">
<img  id="banner" style="max-width:300px;" src="https://i.ibb.co/7Q7rt2k/Banner-prova.png"></a>
</h1>
<br>
<h2><a>Homepage</a></h2>
<h2><a onClick="show_or_hide_Block('downloads_platforms')" href="javascript:void(0);">Downloads</a></h2>
<h3 id="downloads_platforms" class = "hide">
 &gt;<a href="..">Windows</a>
 <br><br>
 &gt;<a href="..">Mac OS X</a>
 <br><br>
 &gt;<a href="..">Linux/Ubuntu</a>
</h3>
</top_menu>
<p id="body_text" style="margin-top:227px;" >
 <h4>Write something above</h4>
 <div class="tab">
 Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 </div>

 <h4>Do you have some text?</h4>
 <div class="tab">
 Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</div>

 <h4>Question</h4> 
 <div class="tab">List of points
 <ul>
  <li >point1;</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  </ul></div>
 <div class="tab">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 <br>
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 </div>
</p>
<bottom_menu> 
 <a class="ver">(v 2.0)</a><br>
 <a class="altro"><a href="./index.html">Back to index</a></a>
</bottom_menu> 
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see I put the image in a h1 tag and i fixed in style.css. Then I wanted the image to be adapted to the window in which is viewed so i made a JS that can adapt the image and the text margin-top. The problem is that my image is trasparent and it does not fill window's width so the text can both scroll behind the image and beside. I don't want neither the text to scroll beside neither behind. How can this be done?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put 
background-color: ;
padding-right: 100%;

Now the text is not show behind the image ad also beside.

```js
function show_or_hide_Block(show_hide){
    if (document.getElementById(show_hide).className == 'hide') {
        document.getElementById(show_hide).className = "show";} 
 else{document.getElementById(show_hide).className = "hide";}
}

 function banner_adapt () {
  var b = document.getElementById("banner");
  b.style.maxWidth="100%";
  var p = document.getElementById("body_text");
   if (b.width >= 700){
    //alert("actual: " + b.width + " too large, setting to 700px.")
    b.style.maxWidth="700px";
   } else if (b.width < 700){
    //alert("Enought small to set 100%.")
    b.style.maxWidth="100%";}
   //alert("setting lar to:" + (Math.round(b.width/1600*449)+10) + "px");
   p.style.marginTop=(Math.round(b.width/1600*449)+10)+ "px";
   
 }

  $(window).load(function(){
   banner_adapt();
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
   banner_adapt();
  });
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f6db75;
}

separatore_iniziale {
  margin-top: 60px;
  }

top_menu {
  font-size: 18px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 10px;
  }

bottom_menu {
  font-size: 18px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 25px;
  }

.ver {
  font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

.altro {
  font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
p{
 z-index: 2;
}

h1{
  margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

h2{
  font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

h3{
  font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

h3.hide {
  display: none;
}

h3.show {
  
}

h4{
  margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
  }

.tab {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  }


ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<top_menu>
<h1><a  href="./index.html">
<img  id="banner" style="max-width:300px; background-color: #EC3711; padding-right:100%;" src="https://i.ibb.co/7Q7rt2k/Banner-prova.png"></a>
</h1>
<br>
<h2><a>Homepage</a></h2>
<h2><a onClick="show_or_hide_Block('downloads_platforms')" href="javascript:void(0);">Downloads</a></h2>
<h3 id="downloads_platforms" class = "hide">
 &gt;<a href="..">Windows</a>
 <br><br>
 &gt;<a href="..">Mac OS X</a>
 <br><br>
 &gt;<a href="..">Linux/Ubuntu</a>
</h3>
</top_menu>
<p id="body_text" style="margin-top:227px;" >
 <h4>Write something above</h4>
 <div class="tab">
 Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 </div>

 <h4>Do you have some text?</h4>
 <div class="tab">
 Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</div>

 <h4>Question</h4> 
 <div class="tab">List of points
 <ul>
  <li >point1;</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  <li >point1</li>
  </ul></div>
 <div class="tab">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 <br>
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
 </div>
</p>
<bottom_menu> 
 <a class="ver">(v 2.0)</a><br>
 <a class="altro"><a href="./index.html">Back to index</a></a>
</bottom_menu> 
</body>

</html>
```